# Printing the contents of a string array using pointers

Tags: c, array, pointers

I'm currently studying C and I'm trying to just print the contents of a string array. I'm using `pNames` to point to the first char pointer and iterating from there.

A more proper approach would use this pointer, get a char* each time and use `printf("%s", pNames[i])` to print a whole string. However, I thought I would try to print it character-by-character inside each string, as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

char *names[] = {
    "John", "Mona",
    "Lisa", "Frank"
};

char **pNames = names;
char *pArr;
int i = 0;
while(i < 4) {

    pArr = pNames[i];
    while(*pArr != '\0') {
        printf("%c\n", *(pArr++));
    }
    printf("\n");
    i++;
}
return 0;
}
```

This code kind of works (prints each letter and then new line). How would you make it better?

Comment: @Michael it's your lucky day, fixed the bug for you, and adjusted the text accordingly. Don't get used to it, we normally review working code here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Given that the code is really simple, I see mostly coding style issues with it.

Instead of this:

> ```
> char *names[] = {
>     "John", "Mona",
>     "Lisa", "Frank"
> };
> ```

I would prefer either of these writing styles:

```
char *names[] = { "John", "Mona", "Lisa", "Frank" };

// or

char *names[] = {
    "John",
    "Mona",
    "Lisa",
    "Frank"
};
```

The `pNames` variable is pointless. You could just use `names`.

Instead of the `while` loop, a `for` loop would be more natural.

This maybe a matter of taste,
but I don't think the Hungarian notation like `*pArr` is great.
And in any case you are using this pointer to step over character by character,
so "Arr" is hardly a good name.
I'd for go for `pos` instead. Or even just `p`.

You should declare variables in the smallest scope where they are used.
For example `*pos` would be best declared inside the `for` loop.
In C99 and above, the loop variable can be declared directly in the `for` statement.

The last `return` statement is unnecessary.
The compiler will insert it automatically and make the `main` method return with 0 (= success).

Putting it together:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *names[] = { "John", "Mona", "Lisa", "Frank" };
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        char *pos = names[i];
        while (*pos != '\0') {
            printf("%c\n", *(pos++));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Actually it would be more interesting to use `argc` and `argv` for something:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
        char *pos = argv[i];
        while (*pos != '\0') {
            printf("%c\n", *(pos++));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Removing the loop and writing `printf("%s\n",argv[i])`. Does that work for printing all the names?

Answer (score 9):

Other points not already mentioned:

### Use `const` where possible

It's better to use `const` where possible so that it's clear when you are intending to modify things and clear when you're not.  This helps the compiler help you find bugs early.

### Avoid magic numbers

It's better to avoid having numbers like `4` in the program.  If you want to change things later, you may well be left wondering "why 4? what does that mean?"  Better would be to assign a constant with a meaningful name.

### Use `putchar` rather than `printf` for single characters

The `printf` function is very useful, but `putchar` is often better suited for single-character output.  The reason is that `printf` has to, at runtime, parse the format string, apply the arguments and then emit the results, while `putchar` only has to pass a character directly to the output.  This particular code isn't exactly performance-critical but it's useful to acquire good coding habits from the beginning.

### Use C idioms

It's more idiomatic C to have a loop like this for the characters:

```
while(*pArr) { /* ... */ }
```

rather than this:

```
while(*pArr != '\0') { /* ... */ }
```

### Consider using a "sentinel" value for the end of a list

There are two common ways to iterate through a list in C.  One is as you already have it, when you know how many values are in the list.  The other way is to use a "sentinel" value -- some unique value that tells the program "this is the end of the list."  For a list of names such as this program has, a rational choice for a sentinel value would be `NULL`.

### Omit the `return 0` from the end of `main`

Uniquely for `main`, if the program gets to the end of the function, it automatically does the equivalent of `return 0` at the end, so you can (and should) omit it.

### Result

Using all of these suggestions, one possible rewrite might look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    const char *names[] = { "John", "Mona", "Lisa", "Frank", NULL };

    for (int i=0; names[i]; ++i) {
        const char *ch = names[i]; 
        while(*ch) {
            putchar(*ch++);
            putchar('\n');
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

With a null sentinal the follwing is pretty simple:

```
for(const char** pNames = names; *pNames; pNames++) {
    /* *pNames points to one of the strings, do something with it */

    const char *pName = *pNames;
    while (*pName) {
        putchar(*pName++);
    }
    putchar('\n');

 }
```

Sure you don't need the {} in the while loop but I prefer to put all block bodies in {}'s since there have been some well known problems when code like:

```
  if (condition) 
      dosomething();
```

was modified to read:

```
  if (condition)
      dosomething();
      dommorestuff();
```

Answer (score 4):

I find this a bit easier to read, and it avoids both magic numbers and a `NULL` at the end of the array:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *names[] = { "John", "Mona", "Lisa", "Frank" };

    int elements = sizeof (names) / sizeof (names[0]);

    for (int i = 0; i < elements; i++) {
        char *p = names[i];
        while (*p)
            putchar(*p++);
        putchar('\n');
    }

return 0;
}
```

Use `printf("%c\n", *p++)` if you want to print one character on a line, like your example did.